# Replacing asp:imagebutton with processing image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, aspbutton

So I have an asp:imagebutton for lets say loginning into a web site.

OnClick the page does xyz and then redirects you, there is a pause time between the redirect from when the button was clicked. To make the wait a bit more user friendly I am replacing the button with a processing image and text the javascript that does this is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ShowProcessing").click(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith("<img src='/content/images/processing.gif' /> Processing");
    });
});
```

This is the button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Login" runat="server" OnClick="Login_Click" CssClass="ShowProcessing" />
```

The problem is the change to processing image happens but the asp OnClick event however does not fire.

Comment: If you remove the jQuery does the event fire as expected? Regardless, you basically just want to _update_ the `src` attribute of the existing element instead of removing from and adding to the DOM.

Comment: the above event fires as expected when the above jquery is removed.

Comment: My resolution, instead of replace, do .hide() followed by .after() which works just as intended. .Replace() removes the OnClick function before it is ever invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.replace()` tried and succeeded with:

```
$(".ShowProcessing").click(function () { 
    $(this).hide(); 
    $(this).after("<img src='/content/images/processing.gif' /> Please wait..." ) 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the entire element with something else entirely, just alter the `src` of the current element:

```
$(".ShowProcessing").click(function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "/content/images/processing.gif");
});
```

This is *if* `ImageButton` is rendered as an `img` proper, somewhere, and not just some funky `input` with scripting (I don't recall off the top of my head, and webforms does some things in strange ways). Then proceed to insert text *after* the existing element as desired.

Comment: I want to keep the above a generic as possible so it can work on any html item that has teh class ShowProcessing label.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you may try to remove the first image and then add the new processing image.

instead of replace use (Remove then add) functions.